# Как на основе кольцевого однонаправленного списка сделать двусвязный?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

Написал код где можно работать с данными из файла (что-то похожее на БД) на основе кольцевого однонаправленного списка, но нужно использовать двунаправленный, не пойму как это сделать в моем коде.
Понимаю, что вопрос звучит глупо, но на лекции мы рассматривали первый вид списков, а второй мне тяжело реализовать в этом коде.

Надеюсь на чью-либо помощь

```
List::List() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    Size = 0;
}

List::~List() {
    Node* temp{};
    std::ofstream f;
    f.open("Data.txt");
    if (f.is_open())
    {
        if (head != nullptr)
        {
            std::string buf{};
            temp = head;
            for (int i{ 0 }; i < Size; i++)
            {
                Combine(temp, &buf);
                f << buf << std::endl;
                temp = temp->pNext;
            }
            std::cout << "Данные успешно загружены в файл" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Список пуст, нечего записывать" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Не удалось записать данные в файл" << std::endl;
    }
    f.close();
    while (Size)
    {
        pop_front();
    }
    std::cout << "Список успешно очищен" << std::endl;
}

void List::Combine(Node* node, std::string* buf) {
    *buf = node->name + node->offers + node->all_offers;
}

void List::Separate(std::string str, std::string data[]) { //разделитель 
    int j{ 0 };
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != ';' && str[i] != '\t')
        {
            if (j != 0 and str[i] == ' ')
            {
                continue;
            }
            data[j] += str[i];
        }
        else if (str[i] == ';')
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void List::Add_Data(std::string data[]) {
    Node* add = new Node;
    add->name = data[0] + "; ";
    data[0] = "";
    add->offers = data[1] + "; ";
    data[1] = "";
    add->all_offers = data[2];
    data[2] = "";
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = tail = add;
        add->pNext = head;
        
    }
    else
    {
        add->pNext = head;
        tail->pNext = add;
        tail = add;
    }
    Size++;
}

void List::List_input() {
    std::ifstream f;
    f.open("Data.txt");
    if (f.is_open())
    {
        std::string str{};
        std::string data[3]{};
        while (!f.eof())
        {
            getline(f, str);
            if (str == "")
            {
                continue;
            }
            Separate(str, data);
            Add_Data(data);
        }

        f.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Не удалось загрузить список" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void List::Show() {
    if (head != nullptr)
    {
        std::string buf{};
        Node* temp{ head };
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < Size; i++)
        {
            Combine(temp, &buf);
            std::cout << buf << std::endl;
            temp = temp->pNext;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Пусто )=" << std::endl;
    }
}

void List::pop_front() {
    Node* temp{ head };
    head = head->pNext;
    delete temp;
    Size--;
}

void List::Set_default() {
    Node* temp{ head };
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < Size; i++)
    {
        temp->name = "Name; "; temp->offers = "0; "; temp->all_offers = "0";
        temp = temp->pNext;
    }
    std::cout << "Сброс данных успешно выполнен." << std::endl;
}

int List::DeleteElement() {
    if (Size == 0) {
        std::cout << "Список пуст." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int n;
    std::cout << "Какой элемент хотите удалить?(Всего элементов " << Size << ").\n";
    while (!(std::cin >> n) || std::cin.peek() != '\n' || n == 0 || n > Size)
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        while (std::cin.get() != '\n');
        std::cout << "Ошибка ввода\n" << std::endl;
    }
    n--;
    Node* temp = head, * helping = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        helping = temp; // предыдущее значение temp
        temp = temp->pNext;
    }

    if (temp == head) // если элемент который надо удалить первый
    {
        head = temp->pNext;
    }
    else
    {
        helping->pNext = temp->pNext;
    }
    std::cout << "Элемент был удалён." << std::endl;
    free(temp);
    Size--; // уменьшаем размер списка
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Для начала надо добавить в тип Node указатель назад (скажем, pPrev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть класс узла, в нем есть указатель на следующий элемент списка. Нужно добавить указатель на предыдущий элемент списка. И при всех операциях в списке, менять оба указателя. Из `class List` поле `Node* tail` можно убрать - в двунаправленном списке можно двигаться в оба направления, достаточно одного указателя на начало. Тогда указатель на конец будет `head->pPrev`.

```
class Node
{ public:
  Node *pNext;
  Node *pPrev; // нужно добавить
  ... // какие-то данные
}
```